# SSH tunneling: first hop username/password, second hop using SSH key

Tags: java, linux, ssh, sftp, ssh-tunnel

For a third party application I'm installing, I need to setup an SFTP connection:

The base app is a java application which runs on a linux/JBOSS machine (machine A). This application uses (s)ftp to connect to a second centOS linux machine (machine B)

The problem I am facing is as follows: the third party application only supports (s)ftp authorization with username and password, while the target machine (B) only allows access using a provided SSH key.

The only solution I can think of, involves tunneling the SFTP connection through an SFTP server on machine A, which does allow username+password SSH. I have no idea if this is possible though, and no idea which tool to use to set this up. Note this has to be a permanent connection so should be set up to work on startup of the server.

I have set up tunneling connections before using only SSH keys and mobaXterm, but the internal workings are still not totally clear to me.

Another challenge in this situation may be that I do not have the possibility for root access on machine B.

**So my question**: is it possible to setup a tunnel connection in such a way that the application on machine A can use username+password to connect to machine B, and what do I need to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Usually I use the following construction:

 `ssh -N -L 21:127.0.0.1:21 ip_address_machine_B` In this command you can use any other ports.

 Then on machine_A you need connect to localhost port 21

Comment: Ah I was hoping for something like that! And connecting to localhost:21 is done using the credentials of the user which runs the ssh command?

Comment: I think you should use credential valid for ftp service.

Comment: okay thanks, on machine A every user can connect to ftp.  Will try this out as soon as i have access to machine B